# objects nested in multiple arrays yield undefined offset error when retrieved

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array in php. I try to

```
   $comp_latlong = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Latitude] => 51.385401
                        [Longitude] => -0.335434
                    )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Latitude] => 52.385401
                        [Longitude] => -0.325431
                    )

            )
    )
```

I'm trying to loop over the array and retrieve the latitude and longitude like so:

```
foreach($comp_latlong as $latlon){

 echo [$latlon[0]->Latitude, $latlon[0]->longitude];

}
```

but I get an `undefined offset error`. My understanding is that the `foreach` would loop through the array of arrays (each array of arrays being assigned the working variable `$latlon`). $latlon[0] gives me the object, and finally I can access the `Latitude` or `Longitude` property by using the pointer like so: `$latlon[0]->Latitude`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the first element of your array is an empty array, it contains no object.
So the call to $latlon[0] is undefined.

Try this :

```
foreach($comp_latlong as $latlon){    
    if (isset($latlon[0])) 
        echo [$latlon[0]->Latitude, $latlon[0]->longitude];    
}
```